# How to join on a column name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an odd thing I was wondering if I could do it with SQL. Let's take the following example where I have 'style data' and I want to join it based on a column:

```
WITH Style (Column, Prop) AS (
    SELECT 'Age', 'background: yellow;'
) SELECT
    Name, Age
  FROM
    Tbl JOIN Style (?)
```

The output that I'd like to get is something like:

```
Name      Age      __STYLE__Age
Tom       20       background: yellow
Sarah     30       background: yellow
```

How could something like that be done for each field, sort of like an expression of (in pseudo-code):

```
CASE WHEN <field_name>=Style.Column THEN Style.Prop END __STYLE__<field_name>
```

Or, is there a way to pass property along at the column level?

Comment: The short answer is no, you can't do this, not without using dynamic SQL (which means writing code which writes SQL statements).  Why do you have this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

**Try Follow:**

```
WITH Style AS (
    SELECT [Name], Age as [Age], 'background: yellow;' as __STYLE__Age
) SELECT
    Name, Age, as __STYLE__Age
  FROM
    Style Join Tbl on Style.Name = Tbl.Name
```

OR

```
WITH Style AS (
    SELECT [Name], Age as [Age], 'background: yellow;' as __STYLE__Age
) SELECT
    Name, Age, as __STYLE__Age
  FROM
    Style Join Tbl on Style.__STYLE__Age = Tbl.__STYLE__Age
```

Comment: ok but here you're just hardcoding all the column names, I could just as well do that.

Comment: @David542
 OK. thanks.